# Content file corrupted when uploaded in a CM if document name has greek chars

Tags: c#, character-encoding, filenet

I have a routine in a DLL I made (C#) that I use to upload a document to a Content Manager (IBM Filent P8).

It works fine but i have a problem with some characters. 
I uploaded a document with file name like 'filenameØ.docx' and it happens that the 'Ø' char in someway causes trouble because the routine always end up fine (the document and the metadata are actually loaded) but the content in the CM is corrupted and unreadable.
The strange thing is that this behavior happens only in web application; in client apps the file is loaded correctly and I can read it back.

Is it probably a charset mistake in some configuration. Can anyone help?

Comment: A webpage has a header which contains the encoding.  The encoding has to be changed.

Comment: Yes, it is setted to utf-8 that includes the Ø char.

Comment: It probably should be windows encoding 1251.  You probably want to add to your request header : CHARSET=windows-1251